# Docker Postgresql UID

Tags: docker

I am having trouble with file permissions with the postgresql image. (similar problem with redis if anyone knows how to help there)
My files are on a synology nas and the volumes are mounted with nfs. I have an user for the service that needs the db and an user that is just here to make backups and therefore needs read permissions to the files. However the file permissions are being changed by postgres and I cannot figure out how to allow the backup user to read the files.

Here is a compilation of my compose files:

```
services:
  postgresql:
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:12-alpine
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      start_period: 20s
      interval: 30s
      retries: 5
      timeout: 5s
    user: "1050:100"
    volumes:
      - persist_postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - nss:/etc/nss:ro
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxx
      - NSS_WRAPPER_PASSWD=/etc/nss/passwd
      - NSS_WRAPPER_GROUP=/etc/nss/group
    networks:
      - default
  backup:
    image: restic/restic
    entrypoint: sh -c
    command: >
      "([ -f /srv/restic-repo/config ] || (restic init --repo /srv/restic-repo; mkdir /srv/restic-repo/tmp)) &&
       restic backup --host myHost --exclude=\"sends\" --no-scan /source &&
       restic forget --keep-hourly 168 --keep-daily 30 --keep-weekly 52 --keep-monthly 60"
    volumes:
      - persist_postgresql:/source
      - target:/srv/restic-repo
    environment:
      - RESTIC_REPOSITORY=/srv/restic-repo
      - RESTIC_PASSWORD=xxx
      - TMPDIR=/srv/restic-repo/tmp
      - RESTIC_CACHE_DIR=/srv/restic-repo/cache
      - RESTIC_COMPRESSION=max
    user: "1051:100"
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "swarm.cronjob.enable=true"
        - "swarm.cronjob.schedule=0 0 * * * *"
        - "swarm.cronjob.skip-running=true"
      restart_policy:
        condition: none

volumes:
  persist_postgresql:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=192.168.xxx,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":xxx/postgresql"
  nss:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=192.168.1.172,nolock,soft,ro"
      device: ":xxx/nss"
```

Comment: You set the two services to different `user:` IDs.  If they use the same uid, do things work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze The different id's are very much intentional. Ideally I would have one user with rw access to the files and no access to the backups, and another user with ro access to the files and rw access to the backups.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's a NFS share, which by default has all users, including root, squashed to `nobody:nogroup`, maybe try your luck setting:

```
backup.user: "65534:65534"
```